# CMK usage in ADF pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created CMK in ADF. I dont know how to consume CMK in ADF, either pipelines or dataflow.

When tried to add the pipeline, I wont get option to select the CMK. Any information is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review the entire process.

1. First we can use to Azure key vault generate a RSA 2048 key.
2. Add the key to the Azure Data Factory.

By default, data is encrypted with a randomly generated Microsoft-managed key. After we generate a RSA 2048 key via key vault, the data will be encrypted by Customer-managed keys(CMK).

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-overview), we can know Customer-managed keys(CMK) is a type of Server-side encryption. It gives us control over the keys, including Bring Your Own Keys (BYOK) support, or allows you to generate new ones.

Similar to [transparent Data Encryption with customer managed keys in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-tw/blog/transparent-data-encryption-with-customer-managed-keys-in-azure-sql-database-generally-available/).
[image]

So we can conclude that Customer-managed keys(CMK) is transparent to users.This encryption only acts on the network layer or the transport layer. In other words, there is no different to us.